# How inform the caller about the failure reason

Tags: exception, methods

I have a method which is supposed to do something and the return value is a boolean (success/failure).

If the method fails, there are a few reasons causing the failure which the caller (user interface layer) can use to show an appropriate message to the user (this way user can fix the problem).

I was thinking of throwing exceptions with appropriate message but failure reasons are part of normal execution path (almost have 20% chance to occur in compare to method success). So exceptions don't make sense.

Another option is defining an enumeration and used it to inform the caller about the failure reason (using a `Tuple` as return type or adding an `out` parameter). I didn't have seen this kind of design before!

What's the best practice to inform the caller about the failure reason ?

Comment: First, be certain that the user will actually want to know the failure  reason. Sometimes, it's best to just say, "Something bad happened".

Comment: @John: I disagree. If the user doesn't care, they can easily ignore excess information. If the user does care, any information which is not made available will be difficult, if not impossible, to obtain. *Always* provide good error reports. (Note that "good" may well mean "just say 'something bad happened', but also include a 'more details' button" - which still requires the callers all the way up to the GUI to know the failure reason, even if it ends up not being displayed to the user.)

Comment: @Dave: There's nothing to disagree about. I suggested he make sure whether the user needs the information. That's not the same as saying the user does not need it.

Comment: @Dave: "Good error reports" are something else to test, or at least I _hope_ you test it. If it's not required, then why code it, and why test it?

Comment: @John: Agreed that it needs to be tested, just like any other code. As for the need, though... As a user, I've run into far too much code that throws opaque error messages at you and refuses to tell anything more than "something bad happened", which makes it impossible to even determine whether I *can* fix the problem, never mind *how* to fix it. This is intensely frustrating and non-useful. As a developer, if my users call with a problem, I can't help them unless they can provide sufficient information for me to determine the problem. Either way, informative error reports are *always* needed.

Comment: @Dave: you have described a use case for logging, not for an error return

Comment: @John: As the user, logs don't tell me whether the problem is because I did something wrong or not, nor do they tell me whether it's a problem I can fix or not, because, for many types of applications (i.e., anything except a pure desktop app), I will not have access to the logs. Without an explanation of the error, all I can do is beat my head against the wall of trying to find an input that will work without knowing whether the problem is even input-related at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no shame in having an exception protocol for the 20% case, unless this is in a very critical path from a performance point of view. Passing in an array into which the status comes out works, but it's going to look ugly.

Comment: I agree.  If boolean for a return value already has meaning, overloading the return type with failure is just adding complication.

Comment: @bmargulies: There's no performance critical path. Should I use custom exceptions (easier to catch, more work to implement) or just an instance of `System.Exception` ?

Comment: @Xaqron: never use custom exceptions unless your callers will catch them and behave differently based on the exception type. Otherwise, `InvalidOperationException` or just `Exception` would be fine.

Comment: @John: So caller will find the reason this way: `if (ex.Message.Contains("some string")) ...`, checking the exception string doesn't seem a good idea!

Comment: @Xaqron: it's not a good idea ever to check the message. You really need to be certain that the caller actually will behave differently based on which exception you throw. If all they will do is display the message, then you'd just as well use `InvalidOperationException` as to use `MyCustomException`.

Comment: @Xaqron: You haven't stated what language you're using, but most languages implement exceptions as objects. Assuming yours does, I would use custom exceptions *which are subclasses* of `System.Exception` (or another standard type). That way, default handling of that standard type will still catch them, but you'll also be able to do custom handling of specific error conditions without resorting to examining the message text (which, I agree, you should **never** do if there's any way to avoid it).

Comment: @Dave: I use C#. If I don't use custom exceptions, because there's no inner exception (I'm throwing them) and `System.Exception` doesn't provide error number, then how I distinguish the exceptions at catching side ? (I think, it's better to ask it as a new question)

Comment: @Xaqron: Basically, you don't... That's why I would use custom exceptions. :) But I would make them subclasses of a standard exception class so that they can be caught either as `MyCustomException` or as `System.Exception` (because they'd be both).