# How to distinguish different plain exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

If I don't want to create custom-exceptions, then how to distinguish them when catching ?

```
if (somethingIsWrong)
   throw new Exception("Something is wrong.");
else if (anotherthingIsWrong)
   throw new Exception("Anotherthing is wrong.");
else
   throw Exception("Nothing is wrong!");

// Now when catching them:

catch (Exception ex)
{
   if (ex.Message.Contains("Something"))
      ShowUserErrorThatSomethinIsWrong();
   else if (ex.Message.Contains("Another"))
      ShowUserErrorThatAnotherthinIsWrong();
   // ...
}
```

I wish if `System.Exception` had a `ErrorNumber` property for customizing exceptions this way:

```
if (somethingIsWrong)
   throw new Exception(1001, "Something is wrong.");

// And catching them this way:

if (ex.ErrorNumber = 1001)
   // ...
```

I know it's possible to extending `MyExceptionClass` from `System.Exception` but is there any better solution ?

This is related to my other question which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054235/how-inform-the-caller-about-the-failure-reason).

Comment: Why don't you want to create custom exceptions?

Comment: It would be very interesting to know why you do not want to create explicit exception classes - as they are the way to go in .NET and will provide you with efficient and hierarchical error catching/filtering... Naturally an error-number can be helpful in pointing to the documentation, but it is a hassle to maintain.

Comment: See here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054235/how-inform-the-caller-about-the-failure-reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact case I would introduce custom exceptions. While you shouldn't create custom exceptions just because you can, if you have a case where there isn't a fitting framework exception or the name would be misleading, create a custom one!

Your proposed code would make it **harder** to distinguish between exceptions, the caller would have to make assumptions about your code. With custom exceptions, this wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Creating your own exception type *is* the solution here.

You *could* set the [`HResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx) on an exception and throw it that way - but it's a horrible thing to do.

The language has been designed to catch exceptions based on their type rather than by error codes.

Of course, if you have several similar exceptions with some extra information which could be of interest to code catching it, you can add that extra information into properties of your custom exception.

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom exceptions by extending `System.Exception` is THE way to go. Why dont you want to do that?

Advantages:

- You could catch all your custom exceptions by class type (rather than using that ugly .contains)
- You could add the ErrorNumber property you want to handle error after catching
- It is the most clean, direct, elegant solution.

Any strong reason not to use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are "supposed" to create your own exceptions in .NET. The exception model works best that way.

If you really want to have an ErrorCode you can create your own Exception and use only that.

```
public class ErrorCodeException : Exception
{
    private readonly int _errorCode;
    public ErrorCodeException(int errorCode)
    {
        _errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public ErrorCodeException(int errorCode, string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        _errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int ErrorCode { get { return _errorCode; } }
}
```

**Edit**
If you for debugging purposes want to find out exactly which of all of your Exceptions that was thrown it is much better to have a look at the stack trace instead of assigning a sequence number to each exception you may throw.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's best not to throw `Exception` objects, because they are too general. There are many classes that derive from `Exception` within the framework, it's usually the case that there's one that fits the scenario you're in. If not, then extend `Exception` with your own custom class.

For example, if you're validating parameters coming into a method and find one is null when it shouldn't be, throw an `ArgumentNullException`. If two things are trying to be done out of order, throw an `InvalidOperationException`. You can catch these exceptions individually:

```
try
{
}
catch (ArgumentNullException argException)
{
}
catch (InvalidOperationException opException)
{
}
```

You might find even this approach too general, but I would say that a high-level component (e.g. a UI) doesn't really need to know the exact details of what's gone wrong, just that "something" went wrong. For example, if something goes wrong with a database command, you might get a `SqlException` thrown. You can catch that, log some details, then throw a more general exception.